# Drop-down menu in navbar with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am copying the code and made possible change in **w3schools code**. The **Dropdown 2**, and **Dropdown 3** `button` is not working.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown 1
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown 2
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
  
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown 3
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Comment: @bestinamir Bootstrap is a sledgehammer, when needle nose pliers are required here. And, since the OP is clearly new to all of this, Bootstrap isn't going to help them understand fundamental coding principles.

Comment: @Scott Marcus why I do use BootStrap, I want to stick to bare bone technology, and have similar functionality which I want. CSS can do anything !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all 3 of your drop downs have the same `id`, which is not allowed. And since all 3 buttons use the same callback and that callback specifically toggles the visibility of that reused `id`, the system stops when it finds the first matching element (because there should never be more than one element with the same `id` in the first place).

The reality is that using `id`s in the first place, while it seems like an easy approach, causes brittle code that doesn't scale (as you've found), so avoid `id`s and use CSS classes and the hierarchy of your HTML elements as your methods for finding elements.

Also, [never use `getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) or [inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991).

Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3 Schools as you can as it is well-known to have incomplete, inaccurate, or just plain wrong information. Instead, you'll get much more comprehensive and up to date information from [The Mozilla Developers Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org), who are the stewards of the JavaScript language.

See the comments below for details:

```js
// Set your events up in JavaScript, not with HTML event attributes
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Loop over all the menus
  document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-content").forEach(function(dd){
    dd.classList.remove("show"); // Hide the menu
  });
    
  // If the clicked element was a button
  if (event.target.classList.contains('dropbtn')) {
    // Show just the menu that corresponds to the clicked button
    event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  } 
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 1</a>
    <a href="#about">About 1</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 2</a>
    <a href="#about">About 2</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button  class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 3</a>
    <a href="#about">About 3</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to differentiate your menus somehow. I used a `data-target` attribute. Also, you need to hide any visible menus before showing. About the button look, just change the css of `.dropbtn` to your liking.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(el) {
  var currentMenu = document.querySelector(".dropdown-content.show");
  if (currentMenu) currentMenu.classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById(el.dataset.target).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-target="dropdown1" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 1</a>
    <a href="#about">About 1</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-target="dropdown2" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 2</a>
    <a href="#about">About 2</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-target="dropdown3" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</button>
  <div id="dropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 3</a>
    <a href="#about">About 3</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.nextElementSibling** ==> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

in your case

```js
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.dropbtn');

allButtons.forEach(btn=>
  {
  btn.onclick=()=>{
    allButtons.forEach(btn_X=>
      {
      let divContent = btn_X.nextElementSibling
      if ( btn===btn_X) divContent.classList.toggle('show')
      else divContent.classList.remove('show')
      })
    }
  })

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick =e=>
  {
  if (e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) return
  allButtons.forEach(btn=>btn.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show'))
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 1</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 1</a>
    <a href="#about">About 1</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 2</a>
    <a href="#about">About 2</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 3</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home 3</a>
    <a href="#about">About 3</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```